# AWS Windows Instance for Service Catalog (YAML Config)

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, remote-desktop

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to update an EFS OnDemand EC2 instance (YAML) to a Windows EC2 instance?

I.e. how to get the user's credentials to login to a launched Windows instance (Remote Desktop)?

Also, has anyone found a way to copy paste from the local machine to the Golden AMI instance?

Answer (score 0):

You go to the EC2 console and click the checkmark for the EC2 instance. Then there's a menu option to show you the password. For copy paste... you should just be able to ctrl+c, ctrl+v just like anywhere else. "Golden AMI" isn't a real thing, it's just a phrase people use to mean "we made this AMI and it's got our special sauce" (could be configs, security scanners, whatever...).

I don't really understand the other question you're asking.

Comment: Cool thanks. 
The ctrl+c, ctrl+v doesn't work in the instance I'm using but does in the ones that aren't approved yet. I'll see if I can get a custom one approved.

The main question doesn't make much sense I guess!
I have made an AMI image of a Windows instance. This needs to go into a Service Catalog as a product. There are other 'products' which are linux EC2s, so I'm using the  yaml code and tweaking for the Windows instance.

The idea is for a user to enter their creds and then be able to login to the remote desktop they spin up with these creds.